# Perl: Comparing two string of two files

Tags: string, perl, file, compare

I have two CSV files. Both have a column that contains the same data, with the difference that one file contains more data in that column than the other.

I want to just print out the rows of `file2` in which contains the same string in that column as in the other file.

For example:

**file1**

```
App_Int1     SID_bla1
App_Int2     SID_bla2
App_Int_4    SID_bla4
```

**file2**

```
SID_bla1     hello     bye    ...
SID_bla2     good      bad    ...
SID_bla5     hey       ho     ....
SID_bla4     hi        cheers ...
```

And I want the output to be like this

```
SID_bla1     hello     bye    ...
SID_bla2     good      bad    ...
SID_bla4     hi        cheers ...
```

Because file1 doesn't contain `SID_bla5`, the row with `SID_bla5` will not be printed.

Here is my code but it doesn't work, can somebody give me some hints?

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = $ARGV[0] || die "Need to get CSV file on the command line\n";
my $mystring = "";

open(my $data, '<', $file) || die "Could not open '$file' $!\n";
my $newfile = "fooNew3.txt";
open(FILE2, ">", $newfile) || die "Could not open file";

my $file2 = "export.txt";
open(my $data2, '<', $file2) || die "Could not open '$file2' $!";

my $mystring2 = "";
my $line2;
my %filehash;
my @fields2 = "";

while ($line2 = <$data2>) {
  chomp $line2;

  @fields2 = split(";", $line2);
  while (my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line;

    my @fields = split(";", $line);
    if ($filehash{ $fields2[0] } eq $fields[1]) {
      # if the first column of file2 is identical with the second column of file1
      # then output the identical string and the second column of file2
      # which belongs to the first column of file2 (which is the identical string)

      print FILE2 join ';', "$fields[1]; $filehash{$fields2[0]} $fields2[1] \n";
    }
```

What would be wrong with this?

```
  if ($fields2[0] eq $fields[1] {
    print $fields2[0] $fields2[1] $fields2[2];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As a perl script, your code could be simplified to the following:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 File1 File2\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my $file2 = pop;

my %seen;
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    $seen{$F[1]}++;
}

local @ARGV = $file2;
while (<>) {
    my @F = split;
    print if $seen{$F[0]};
}
```

Comment: I don't think you meant that the OP's code could be simplified like that? After all he says that what he has written doesn't work. I would also prefer that you kept `@F` for command-line programs. Capital letters means global variables, and `my @F` is just wrong!

Comment: No @Borodin, not his literal code, his intent :).  Accepting two files from the command line, processing each of those files, outputting the result.

Comment: As a 99.9% rule, I would agree with leaving capital letters for global variables or more specifically constants.  However, I believe this is a special case where making a connection to the autosplit `-a` flag is a means of making the code more self-documenting for anyone familiar with command line parsing.  If there was a special flag for it, like there is for in place editing with `$^I`, I would've used that, but this probably works better.

Comment: But you wrote, *"your code could be simplified to the following"*. That doesn't even hint at the intent. And I realise where `@F` came from, but I believe that self-documentation *"for anyone familiar with command line parsing"* at the expense of all others is misguided. A simple `@fields` is self-documenting to all

Comment: Yes, I'm personifying his code.  The code his script WANTS to be.  Perhaps anthropomorphism isn't always taken as it's intended in a world of programmers thinking literally, but I don't think some loose language in this case is that harmful.  Of course I'm not going to simplify and reproduce the broken nature of his code, but I can understand its intent without actually reading the details.  A bicycle is still a bicycle even if it's missing a wheel, a breakpad, and the gears are rusted, and most of us can recognize it as such without actually giving it a close examination :)

Comment: Or you could just say, *"your problem could be solved by the following:"*!

Comment: Yes, perhaps what looked from a distance like a bicycle was actually a washing machine on its side, and I was giving his code more credit than it deserved.  That would make your text more accurate.  As always, if something bothers you, feel free to just edit my solutions, I don't anticipate ever being offended ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are over-engineering the problem.

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR {a[$2]; next}$1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt
SID_bla1     hello     bye    ...
SID_bla2     good      bad    ...
SID_bla4     hi        cheers ...
```

If you want to use Perl, invoke it with `-ap` for autosplit and auto loop over each line and print.

If your data are `;`-separated, such as

**file1.txt**

```
App_Int1;SID_bla1
App_Int2;SID_bla2
App_Int_4;SID_bla4
```

**file2.txt**

```
SID_bla1;hello;bye;...
SID_bla2;good;bad;...
SID_bla5;hey;ho;....
SID_bla4;hi;cheers;...
```

You could just set the field separator to be `;`:

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR == FNR {a[$2]; next}$1 in a' file1.txt file2.txt
SID_bla1;hello;bye;...
SID_bla2;good;bad;...
SID_bla4;hi;cheers;...
```

Comment: I tried it with gawk but it also doesn't work, how can I let it print into another file? my columns are separated with semicolons

Comment: @user3507732 Perhaps you should put samples of your _actual_ data if you really want someone to help you parse it?

Comment: Hi veryhungrymike, that worked just fine with the example data but it didn't work for the actual data set because it's too large I think...

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't described it well, what I *think* you want is all of the lines in `file2` whose first column matches *any* of the values in the second column of `file1`. This short Perl program will do that for you.

I have assumed the fields in your files are separated by any mixture of whitespace - spaces or tabs. It works by building a hash from the data in `file1` that has a *true* value for every string appearing in the second column of each record. That is all that is needed from the first file.

Then `file2` is opened and processed. The first field in each line is checked using the hash, and the line is printed if there is a corresponding hash element.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $fh;
my %wanted;

open $fh, '<', 'file1.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  $wanted{$fields[1]} = 1;
}

open $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';
while (<$fh>) {
  my @fields = split;
  print if $wanted{$fields[0]};
}
```

**output**

```
SID_bla1     hello     bye    ...
SID_bla2     good      bad    ...
SID_bla4     hi        cheers ...
```

Comment: Hello Borodin, at the second last line of your code "print if $wanted{$fields[0]};" I always get the error: Use of uninitialized value $_ in print. And I have a question about $wanted{$fields[1]} = 1; //the value 1 is given to the 2. column of the file1.txt, what does that mean?

Comment: @user3507732: You must have changed the `while` loop. Please open another question and show the entirety of your new code